# How should we handle questions about the 2022 war in Ukraine?

Tags: discussion, current-events

There will doubtless be hundreds of questions from old and new users about claims about the war in Ukraine, and it might be good to discuss how to handle them *before* it gets out of hand.

Personally I do not think Skeptics.SE is a good place to discussing real-time events like this, and the close reasons agree:

> **Questions about unresolved current events** […] are off-topic because there is insufficient data for a meaningful answer.

It's a far better place to discuss the war *after* things have settled down, and well researched and peer reviewed sources can be compared. There is of course a [meta](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/handling-news-questions-about-current-events/2870#2870) discussion about it, and probably more.

However, there is a reason someone drew this excellent comic:
[image: XKCD Comic #386]

There will be a lot of information posted that is clearly *wrong*, and the urge to have someone else say it's false is strong. There is however a time and place for everything, and I don't think that "something is trending on twitter and it looks shady" should be enough to immediately post it here, at least not if it discusses something that just happened.

I'm not really sure where I'm going with this. At the moment I've flagged everything about the war as "current event", I guess I just want to know what others think about it.

Comment: Isn't the [tag:russo-ukranian-war] tag misspelled (or misspelt, in that other English)?

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a good question. It is a hard question. It gets to what people need from us versus what we can do to help them.

There are competing forces here we need to balance, so ultimately my answer is "It depends."

---

I think we want to fight misinformation as part of our *raison d'etre*, but that misinformation comes in many forms.

- Some of the claims we tackle are pure, innocent Urban Legends. Someone thought a story was true. Someone didn't understand a legal term.

No-one is working to defend these errors, and we can easily correct them.

- Some of the claims we tackle are scams and marketing tripe. They are deliberate lies, but they only exist for a simple profit motive.

I think we do well against such claims, showing that they are not supported by evidence.

- Some of the claims we tackle are more about bolstering people's ideologies - e.g. that statements in the Bible are all literally true, that Ayurvedic approaches are more effective that modern medicine, that Germ Theory is wrong.

Not only are these claims harder to persuade people about (because
changing your mind means changing who you are as a person), but, more
relevantly here, they are promoted by organised groups of
propagandists.

- Some claims, however, are put out by nation-state level propagandists. It is difficult to pin down motivations, but it is understood that for this level of propaganda, it isn't necessary for people to *trust* these claims; it is sufficient that the targets no longer trust *any* claims. The goal isn't to promote a particular lie, but just to obscure true information, so people can't act on it.

The idea of tackling such machinery is daunting, but throwing up our hands and saying "It is too hard to even bother" is precisely what the propagandists are aiming for. We should not give up so easily; showing that evidence-based approaches can cut through lies is important.

So this is an argument FOR letting recent claims about the [Russo-Ukrainian War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo-Ukrainian_War) be tackled here.

[These categories aren't hard and sharp. For example, I would suggest US political parties (and their donors) have greater funding for propaganda than many nation states. I also am a big fan of answers that show the claim is *true*, despite my doubts when I first saw the question; let's not forget them!]

---

Skeptics.SE users are *not* forensic investigators who can examine on-scene evidence and have powers to compel people to answer. We are not journalists, funded to rush into war-zones with cameras and microphones. We are not Internet sleuths, coming up with our own amateur theories and original research, like [Reddit](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-22214511).

We largely popularise the evidence-based conclusions that have already been reached.

So, when people ask questions that try to pre-empt the conclusions of court cases, of official inquiries or are likely being investigated by dozens of international journalists, I think they somewhat overestimate what we might be capable of achieving.

We have a close reason for current events, precisely because it is too early for firm conclusions to be published.

So this is an argument AGAINST letting recent claims about the Russo-Ukrainian War be tackled here.

---

So, how do we balance these two forces? I think it depends on the question...

These questions strike me as relatively simple yes/no fact-based claim that should not take very long to be confirmed or refuted by journalists:

- [Did a Turkish cargo ship get bombed in the Black Sea during the Russian invasion of Ukraine?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53057/did-a-turkish-cargo-ship-get-bombed-in-the-black-sea-during-the-russian-invasion)
- [Did the Russian 74th motorised rifle brigade surrender in February '22?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53060/did-the-russian-74th-motorised-rifle-brigade-surrender-in-february-22)

This (currently closed) question doubts the existing output of journalists, so will take longer to resolve:

- [Did Ukraine's army manage to destroy 15 T-72 Russian tanks in Hlukhiv, Sumy region, with Javelins?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53066/did-ukraines-army-manage-to-destroy-15-t-72-russian-tanks-in-hlukhiv-sumy-regi)

This (currently closed) question asks about the motivation of an army. It *might* one day be the subject of a War Crimes tribunal, and we would get an answer then.

- [Are there independently verified cases of Russia targeting Ukraine's civil buildings?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53064/are-there-independently-verified-cases-of-russia-targeting-ukraines-civil-build)

Because these are line-ball decisions, I think we can have legitimate (hopefully minor) disagreements about where the line should be drawn, and I hope regulars will help keep the mods in line with the community here. Close/re-open votes are the ideal mechanism, but with comments and meta-questions too.

---

A similar question was asked in 2014: [Should we handle Ukraine-related propaganda](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2711/should-we-handle-ukraine-related-propaganda). My thinking on the answer has changed slightly, but not a lot.

Comment: My main concern is with everything that is going on what could be accepted as fact/truth today could be shown as false/misinformation tomorrow and we should not rush to answer.

Comment: @JoeW: That is true of every answer here. If we have good evidence, we should answer with the good evidence. If better evidence comes along later, we should update our understanding. If we don't have good evidence, it shouldn't be answered. If we are confident we can't get good evidence YET because it is too soon, close it as Unresolved current event.

Comment: But we should not just say "There is misinformation out there, so there is no point applying scientific skepticism to a claim."

Comment: I think that this is a special case and there is more evidence of propaganda on both sides spreading and masquerading as questions on various stack exchange sites.

Comment: Maybe we are talking at cross-purposes here. I am concerned about bad actors posting on Twitter, Facebook, Reddit and Tinder. Are you concerned about bad actors posting on SE?

Comment: What's true of answers here: If we have a popular question, we tolerate & even upvote answers long enough even without good evidence. If better evidence comes along later, we should update our answers, but all the votes that accumulated in the meantime make that futile. Without good evidence, it shouldn't be answered, but we vote so much into HNQ that our own knees are riddled with self-inflicted bullets. We can be confident that in war there is lots of lying & propaganda, & the emotional side-taking on SE will trump reason & rationality & that CV takes often too long to avoid HNQ damage.

Comment: Yes, I am concerned about bad actors on SE. Get a question posted and provide an answer saying that the claim is false and a few days later information comes out that the claim might be true. When that happens it hurts the credibility of the site. An example of this is the claim about the island where the Ukrainian soldiers died and how that might not have happened as people initially claimed.

Comment: @JoeW: Firstly, do you mean [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53071/as-of-february-25-2022-were-13-ukrainian-border-guards-killed-on-zmiinyi-snak)? It was closed within hours; are you happy with its treatment? The idea of bad actors using Skeptics.SE is a concern, but not enough to block off a whole facet of misinformation, IMO. The notability demands are the first protection. The second is that the truthful answers tends to leave the propagandist very embarrassed. This isn't the greatest place to try that sort of game.

Comment: That was just one of many questions and we already do have a close reason of this is a ongoing event and I see no reason to not use it here.

Comment: "I see no reason" Welp, I just wrote a few hundred words giving a reason: to fight misinformation.

Comment: @Oddthinking That goes back to why I posted the image about "someone being wrong on the internet". There's a lot of places to fight misinformation - Stack Exchange is a very bad place for doing that _in real time_. That's why there's a "ongoing event" reason.

Comment: @Pipe: I am not arguing against using the Close reason for a particular question. I am arguing against a blanket rule for Ukraine or a policy that ends up devolving to "You may only learn the truth when it isn't important or when it isn't relevant any more".

Comment: With this "may only learn the truth when it isn't important or when it isn't relevant any more" we tarnished the site already with all the CovidBS. Has truth an expiration date? To the contrary. How would you have spotted Saddam's WMDs, [the other lies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nayirah_testimony) when 'they were relevant'. The war mongers & lockdowners & maskers & national-vaccinists & other PsyOps have much better PR than homeopaths & lizard spotters. A lie is halfway round the world before the truth has got its boots on. And the side-takers are rife on SE, look at our record or PolSE.

Comment: @LangLangC: Lost me. I understand you don't agree with the consilience about COVID-19, but that is not relevant here. No-one is suggesting the truth has an expiration date. I *am* suggesting that life is a "real-time system"; one in which a late answer is considered "wrong". If propagandists can make it so people only understand the truth after the election/war/whatever, they have won. The propagandists won, IMO, with the WMD story. There's a balance: We can't answer questions before the evidence is in, but it is pointless to be 20 years late.

Comment: I'd even agree that 'knowing better' is better sooner than later, but 1. RTS/"lost" is again side-taking, having agendas besides 'truth' (1 of them _is_ politics) 2. the insane Covdian fallout _is_ relevant; same pattern as we see [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/53077/41728). Not even HNQ, but as too often there are _regulars_ upvoting subpar stuff, clearly, _very_ clearly in this case. Perhaps just a tiny vote more & the horde of the SE-agitariat start their mass distortion. Skeptical S:SE users might fall occasionally, but there seem always enough regulars falling gladly?

Comment: @LangLangC: I don't feel wanting to know the truth in time to make decisions is having an agenda. I continue to reject your characterisation of the consilience around COVID-19 as insane, so I reject that we have failed here. I don't know what the pattern is you are talking about. That particular answer is from a first-timer, and has already been marked as not having references. I fear we are going in circles again.

Comment: The pattern consists of  two aspects: like with Covid-mania, we failed to insist on sound science, delivered half-answers etc (looking at masks in particular), tackled strawmen, and attacked ferociously correct answers for subpar reasons. How many anti'consilience' comments have I read that appealed to emotions/morals, rejected basic principles (like for articles with just RRR but w/o ARR fail in-the-field-agreed upon standards ("would be new"…?), real science would be "unethical" (all RCTs for masking failed, no new ones coming)…) 2. Here it is the _7 UVs,_ not from 1st-timer but regulars!

Comment: Now enjoy the shitshow that SE & more so its many undisciplined users produce like here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376743/ Do you think really this is not raining down on S:SE with regulars (some of which already changed their avatars to suite) or what havoc this will cause on HNQs? Just compare [S:SE's take](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/53096/) predictably bad, with [US-Nuland's testimony](https://rumble.com/vwuz8o-victoria-nuland-warns-of-ukrainian-biological-facilities-falling-into-russi.html). S:SE is unsuited to do this, esp lacking your support, & we get an echo chamber.

Comment: @LangLangC: I have instructed you before on the best way to deal with posts you don't think are good enough. I don't know what your objection is to the cited question, I see no comments, flags or edits from you on it. Your comment here isn't going to lead to its improvement.

Comment: Where we seem to differ: If the questions about Ukraine are the same quality as the COVID ones, I will be happy. Your position on COVID seems to be at odds with not just HNQ visitors, but Skeptics.SE regulars, cited evidence and the positions of scientific organisations.

Comment: My positions on Covid-topics around here is 1. that bad quality in Q&A gets pushed if it fits the prevailing narrative, no matter how ludicrous at first glance or on later revisitation it is. 2. This is exemplary on eg masking: the posts on that here are rubbish, and my position on 'masks' is mostly compatible with my professional medical org (+others) on em: eg all cloth has always been less than useless, N95 not useful for the general public as mandated. Don't kid yourself over 'my position', even if you are yourself a staunch believer or misinformed by mainstream media or Skeptics posts.

Comment: Last part of your comment _is the problem:_ as long as you as a mod do not even recognize the problem with the posts and the behaviour (that with HNQ _starts_ with the regulars here) it's foolish to write against the opinion of masses, against yours, and even your editing away of valid info, facts, reasoning, glorious evidence, that you simply declare irrelevant or political or ranty. Some regulars attack even basic & agreed upon in the field concepts of medicine, science or sci-comm, and seldom is there support for my posts from users (not even counting the 'just rude' ones). That's telling.

Comment: Consider the comments on RCTs as better evidence than bullshit modelling, as RCTs "would be unethical"; RRR vs ARR, where I insist on 'proper procedure', but we all seem to enjoy enduring hysterical amateur wisecracking comments in company of posts that "this would be unusual", yet: https://www.healthnewsreview.org/toolkit/tips-for-understanding-studies/absolute-vs-relative-risk/ or https://academic.oup.com/ndt/article/32/suppl_2/ii13/3056571 If you yourself are satisfied with that level of obedient 'fact-checking' displayed here, then your interventionist editing guarantees worse info.

Comment: Is there help/meta commentary that elaborates on the "current/ongoing events" close reason?

Answer (score 6):

It is a current and ongoing event which is already one of the accepted close reasons. For now that is how I would suggest dealing with these questions as the answers could change hourly/daily depending on what new information we get.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. I'm surprised that we're not already closing questions about it for this very reason.

Comment: It could be useful to create a meta post addressing this and feature it so that users will see it on the front page.

Comment: @LShaver I recently made another question about related issues as well that I saw on another site hit with questions about this.

Comment: @F1Krazy Yet it doesn't seem like a high priority judging by the front page. 4 out of 5 Ukraine questions are still open, two posted by a user with a very high reputation, and they have obviously been seen by a diamond-mod. I guess there's a lot of users who think this is ok and _don't_ chime in.

Comment: @pipe Even on politics the most that is being done in a lot of questions is just protecting it.

Answer (score -1):

This close reason is **certainly** not ipso facto applicable to questions on the Russo-Ukrainian war.

Take for example the question [Was Kyiv's Babyn Yar memorial bombed by Russia in the 2022 Military Operation?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/53082/3835) This we can speak of with relative certainty: there is no *more* information that will come of this. There is no ongoing investigation and all sides have spoken about it and reached consensus. If this kind of question is *not* on topic here then whatever logic is being used to close that question would be applicable to far more.

And if it remains closed, then at what time would these questions be on-topic?

Comment: Frankly your question seemed rather cheezy/gamey. You already seemed to know the answer. Yeah, there's the "self-answers are ok" policy, but if I had 5c every time something posted already on fact-checking site gets self-answered here...

Comment: @Fizz it wasn't on a fact checking site. And, i didn't know the answer. That's why I only answered it myself after researching it for a day.

Comment: I mean the BBC report that you linked *in your Q* (rather than A) had *plenty* of details: "Staff were initially unable to access the Babyn Yar site to assess the damage. However, it is now known that the most iconic memorials in the park are unscathed. These include a large menorah, newly built synagogue and a monument honouring the Soviet citizens and prisoners of war who died, which is located closest to the TV tower. A museum building which was not yet in use caught fire [...]" And yeah, that link was even in the 1st revision of your Q https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/revisions/53082/1

Comment: @Fizz That it didn't damage the "most iconic memorials" doesn't mean the memorial wasn't bombed. The question is principally was it bombed. There is a difference between bombing a memorial and not damaging anything, and bombing a TV tower near a memorial. The argument that the memorial itself was bombed is simply incorrect. The grave site was bombed. This would be egregious and antisemitic imho if it wasn't for the fact that a strategically important TV tower was built on top of the site in 1961, AFTER the graves were moved.

Comment: This is where this site shines. I clarified all of this in my answer, and I think fairly. I feel we lost something great closing that question. I put a lot of work into it and it's fair to be skeptical over the claim "was the memorial bombed", and there was enough information to answer it then.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is a case where I evaluated a claim I was skeptical of made by Ukraine and came into it very harshly critical of Russia, and left thinking they did nothing wrong. MSM infrastructure (though not the journalists) has always been a fair target in war. In any conflict TV towers are the first to go.