# Should we be more vigilant about closing Israel-Hamas conflict questions where reliable information doesn't exist?

Tags: discussion

There seems to be many inflammatory claims being made about actions by both sides in this conflict. Due to the nature of the situation it seems like many if these will be hard to verify or debunk. The problems I see is not only how current the events are but the fact that there seems to be contradicting information about some of these claims making it hard to verify what is true and what is false.

Should we be more vigilant about closing these types of questions about closing these questions as a current event until more information can be found?

I am asking this because of the rise of questions such as did side X kill Y children/civilians/hostages and and other such questions that can't be easily answered.

Comment: Related https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/how-should-we-handle-questions-about-the-2022-war-in-ukraine

Comment: And problem is not just with Qs, but with answers too. E.g. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56221/does-hamas-divert-humanitarian-aid-donations-towards-the-military-budget Almost everything in that answer was contested in comments, sometimes with [other] sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issues raised for Skeptics.SE by the [2023-israel-hamas-war](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2023-israel-hamas-war) are identical to the issues raised by the [russo-ukrainian-war](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russo-ukrainian-war) and others before it.

I stand behind my answer on [that topic](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/how-should-we-handle-questions-about-the-2022-war-in-ukraine) - in brief: the decision of whether to close it should be made on a per question basis, based on whether the evidence is likely already available and we can contribute to the fight against misinformation, or whether we will just have to wait like everyone else to find out.

However, I did see the suggestion (and now I can't find it now to give the author credit; I apologise) [Stop Press: It was @LShaver in a comment [here](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4830/23)] that we carefully word a FAQ-like meta-question on the subject, and add it as a highlighted post, so we can easily point to it when any such questions arise, and to remind high-rep users to use their close votes if they think it is unanswerable at the moment. I am open to this; anyone want to write it?

Comment: Maybe we need to create an overarching meta question that covers all types of conflicts like this. The answer to that can be the FAQ with how we handle questions that can't really be answered when asked. If we do that we can mark this question as well as the Ukraine related one as a duplicate of it.

Comment: @JoeW: The closest I can find to an existing over-arching one is [here](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/549/handling-current-events/4923#4923), but the Current Event close reason came later so that answer hasn't got much love.

Comment: But more to the point, I am thinking a flavour-of-the-month specific post, so it appears more prominently in the box in the top right to try to avoid unanswerable questions.

Comment: Hmmmm.... Why don't I ask the **meta-question**, and let the community word the best answer?

Comment: I think that would work, I was thinking of conflicts like this and Ukraine because of how heated they can become but if you got an idea for a more generic question that would be better. Once that question gets asked feel free to mark this as a duplicate of that.