# (IMO) There are inconsistencies between Skeptic On-topic criteria and some existing questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, off-topic

In [this meta post](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4992/61574), It has been explained that (about Hamas-Israel War of course)

> Your questions must contain a specific claim that can be empirically answered from available evidence.

1. (As I am new to skeptic forum) What I understand from this line is that we are just allowed to transfer specific climes into the skeptic forum and nothing else we are allowed to claim ourselves.
   In other words, this forum is just a tool that saves users time (instead of searching hours and days on Google, websites, news, etc.). Am I right?
2. What confused me are some of the posts on this forum. For example

> [Were babies found with their heads decapitated in Israel after the Hamas attack?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/56115/61574)

that asks

> Is it true?

This, in my opinion, falls into the [following criteria](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4993/61574):

> In short, if the BBC, CNN, the NYT and Reuters are all still trying to find an answer of a question in order to report on it, asking the question here isn't going to get you an answer any faster. The question will likely be closed until the journalists can catch up.

or even

> Questions about unresolved current events and issues currently under investigation by a court of law, government, or other similar investigative body are off-topic because there is insufficient data for a meaningful answer.

Isn't? Obviously this is (not now but was for 12 OCT) an unresolved current event and issue that is currently under investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this meta-question is questioning the decision of the community and mods not to close one particular question immediately.

Short answer: Yep. In hindsight, I wish it had been closed.

It was a line-call. It got a number of close votes from the community, but just too few to be closed.

The fact that the top answer has had to be edited repeatedly as new news came in demonstrates the reason for the policy.

It was the first of the current rush of Israel-Hamas war questions, which has brought an influx of (a) propaganda claims to look at, and (b) people very desperate to make sure their team's propaganda gets included in the answers and comments, and the other team gets painted as subhuman. [I am not belittling the horror of the scenes we are seeing; I think the worst way to honour the dead and prevent more joining them is to promote lies about them.]

As a result, the mods were dealing with some other more serious infractions at the time.

I think we are back on top of it now, but there will continue to be line-call decisions to be made by the community.

At this stage, I think enough evidence has been gathered that it would be perverse to close the question now.