# Propaganda Questions

Tags: discussion, politics

I noticed on Politics Meta that a recent post was made about protecting the site from propaganda questions related to current events surrounding Ukraine and was wondering if anything like that was happening or if anything like that should be done.

[What measures are taken to protect the site from propaganda posts during the ongoing war between Russia and Ukraine?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/what-measures-are-taken-to-protect-the-site-from-propaganda-posts-during-the-ong)

I see a similar question from 2014 but I feel that this needs to be addressed again with a new question.

[Should we handle Ukraine-related propaganda](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2711/should-we-handle-ukraine-related-propaganda)

I also think that the question asking about questions related to the war in general is different as the responses would be different depending on the intent of each question

[How should we handle questions about the 2022 war in Ukraine?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/how-should-we-handle-questions-about-the-2022-war-in-ukraine)