# Can we ask a question that its claim can't be debunked or confirmed?

Tags: discussion

On two occasions we can't debunk or approve a claim:

1. It's not mentioned in the sources.
2. The claim is very new; so there are no sources about the matter.

How can we deal with these questions here?

Comment: Can you give an example of such a claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two questions here.

If a claim isn't mentioned in the sources, then the sources are not a [suitable notability reference](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2497/must-every-questioned-notable-claim-include-a-referenced-citation-with-a-quote). If you see such a question, please attempt to find a better reference and edit it in. If that fails, vote that the question be closed as not a [notable claim](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable).

If a claim is very new because it is a current news event, and the professional searchers for the truth (law enforcement, courts, coroners, journalists, etc.) haven't had a chance to do their jobs, then it should be closed as a [Current Event](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/549/handling-current-events).

In theory, this applies to new scientific hypotheses: if the scientific world hasn't had a chance to consider a new idea, or if it is still being thrashed out in the literature without a clear consilience, it could be argued that it is "research level" and is out of scope. However, we are generally a little more tolerant of just leaving such questions unanswered.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding source free claims

> Can we ask a question that its claim can't be debunked or confirmed?

Stictly speaking, nothing in reality can be debunked or confirmed with apodictic certainty, and because of that, the answer should be a resounding "yes".

But "Yes" only insofar as something related to the event can be agreed to as have actually happened. For example:

---

- Mr. Rich is dead.

  - Was found with two bullet holes in the back of his head, and hanging from a noose in the woods 30 miles from his home.
- [No source upon Cause of Death.]

---

1. You may not know of a source, however one may exist.
2. The circumstances around the death could produce a likely answer.
3. The circumstances could also rule out other answers. `Person A probably did not commit suicide`

If one can at least confirm that the person in question is dead, then the question should be left open. Absent this, close it.

Comment: The question "is Mr Rich dead?" and "Did Mr Rich's soul go to Heaven?" are qualitatively different questions. The former can be [to quote Gould] "confirmed to such a degree that it would be perverse to withhold provisional assent". The latter can never be confirmed or refuted with evidence. The questions should be treated differently on this site - the latter has no place here.